# Android synchronize animations on two image views

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I am animating two image views both having the width of the screen. As soon as the first image starts translating in the x direction right(moving off the screen) the second image appears at the far left of the screen filling the gap of the first image. They continue to move in a infinite cycle. It gives the impression of a rolling scenery.

Everything works perfectly except the line where two images meet. That line flicks. I synchronized the
translation of the images by setStartDelay() method. I also tried using AnimationListener. But that merging line of the two images always flicks.

How to solve this issue or what is the best way to do this animation?

Comment: I've had some issues with a line between adjacent images, and the solution was to overlap them. If their alphas are not 1, you need to half the alphas where overlapped in order to get the right result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are saying to overlap the images by 1 or 2 pixel. If the images are opaque where they overlapped, decrease the opacity( or increasing transparency) of the overlapped region. Am I right? I will give it a try.

Comment: that's right. I think I did about 5px before.